# Por que apenas salva o último registro na tabela?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, input, radiobutton

Galera, uma ajudinha aqui, por favor!

```
<%= form_tag(portabilizar_portabilidades_path, name: 'form', method: :get) do %>
      <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>Nº do contrato</th>
            <th>Nova parcela</th>
            <th>Verba proponente</th>
            <th>Ação</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <% @autorizacoes.each do |autorizacao| %>
            <tr>
              <td><%= radio_button_tag "autorizacao", autorizacao.id %></td>
              <td><%= autorizacao.numero_contrato %></td>
              <td>
                <input class="string required form-control" placeholder="Digite um valor" type="text" name="nova_parcela" id="portabilidade_nova_parcela">
              </td>
              <td>
                <%= collection_select( :portabilidade, :verba, Verba.all, :id, :descricao, {prompt: "Selecione a verba"}, {class: "form-control"} ) %>
              </td>
              <td><%= submit_tag "Portabilizar", :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-portabilizar', :disabled => true %></td>
            </tr>
          <% end %>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    <% end %>
```

Essa é minha view e meu controller é esse:

```
  def portabilizar

    @autorizacao = Autorizacao.find(params[:autorizacao])
    autorizacao_selecionada = params["autorizacao"].to_i
    @nova_parcela = params[:nova_parcela].to_i
    @verba_proponente = params[:portabilidade][:verba]
```

Eu só preciso que ao clicar no meu radiobutton, digite o valor no input, clique no botão e salve os valores. Porém só está acontecendo isso com o último registro. Os registros anteriores estão sendo salvos como null, como resolver isso? Não sei o que estou fazendo de errado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eu acho que seria melhor se você fizesse da seguinte forma:

```
  <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Nova parcela</th>
        <th>Ação</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% @autorizacoes.each do |autorizacao| %>
        <%= form_tag(portabilizar_portabilidades_path, method: :get) do |f| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= radio_button_tag "autorizacao", autorizacao.id %></td>
            <td><%= autorizacao.numero_contrato %></td>
            <td>
              <%= text_field_tag "nova_parcela", '', class: "string required form-control", placeholder: "Digite um valor" %>
            </td>
            <td>
              <%= collection_select( :portabilidade, :verba, Verba.all, :id, :descricao, {prompt: "Selecione a verba"}, {class: "form-control"} ) %>
            </td>
            <td><%= submit_tag "Portabilizar", :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-portabilizar', :disabled => true %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Eu ja cheguei a fazer isso uma vez. Isso gera um formulario para cada autorizacao e o problema é que vou poder marcar vários radiobuttons e nao pode ser assim... A solução que todos falam é por um name diferente, tipo <input type="seu_type" name="model[N][attribute]">. Porém, eu nao sei implementar isso de forma alguma la no meu controller...

Answer (score 0):

Faz assim então:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th>Nova parcela</th>
    <th>Ação</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <% @autorizacoes.each do |autorizacao| %>
        <%= form_tag(portabilizar_portabilidades_path, method: :get) do |f| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= radio_button_tag "radio_autorizacao", autorizacao.id %></td>
      <td><%= autorizacao.numero_contrato %></td>
      <td>
        <%= text_field_tag "nova_parcela", '', class: "string required form-control", placeholder: "Digite um valor" %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= collection_select( :portabilidade, :verba, Verba.all, :id, :descricao, {prompt: "Selecione a verba"}, {class: "form-control"} ) %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= hidden_field_tag "autorizacao", autorizacao.id %>
        <%= submit_tag "Portabilizar", :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-portabilizar', :disabled => true %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```